# Disallowed host with Django, Kubernetes and a Load Balancer on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: django, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm just getting started with GCP and Kubernetes Engine. So far I managed to start a Kubernetes cluster, run my app in a pod and connect it to a Cloud SQL instance. I also added a load balancer so now my app has a static IP and I should be able to connect to it from the outside.

However, I just get a `DisallowedHost` error? Which IP should I allow? The IP of the pod that is completely random or the IP of the load balancer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, it's the IP of the load balancer. In the settings.py file I changed the allowed hosts to

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [os.environ.get('LOAD_BALANCER_IP', '127.0.0.1')]
```

and in my deployment yaml I added the load balancer IP as an evironment variable to my container:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
      - name: LOAD_BALANCER_IP
        value: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

This way I can have the app work automatically both on deploy to the kubernetes cluster and on localhost for development.

Comment: There are lots of different ways to set this up, and so answer will vary accordingly. For me, I had to install `django-allow-cidr` and add my GCP VPC subnet to `ALLOWED_CIDR_NETS` to get it working.

Comment: If you want to use dynamic pod HostIp instead of fixed load balancer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224706/9247792