# DisallowedHost Django deployment in Kubernetes cluster: Invalid HTTP_HOST header

Tags: django, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a Django deployment for a frontend service in my Azure Kubernetes cluster with some basic configuration. But note that the same question applies for my local Minikube cluster. I fetch my Django frontend container image from my remote container registry and expose `port 8010`. My service configuration is quite simple as well.

**frontend.deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-v1
  labels:
    app: frontend-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend-v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend-v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend-v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          image: yourremotename.azurecr.io/frontend-remote:v1
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8010
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: acr-secret
```

**frontend.service.yaml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: frontend-v1
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend-v1
  ports:
  - NodePort:
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8010
    targetPort: 8010
  type: NodePort
```

Now, when I access my deployed frontend service in the browser *i.e.  http://172.17.194.253:31436* with Django's setting `DEBUG = True`, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/http/request.py", line 122, in get_host
    raise DisallowedHost(msg)

Exception Type: DisallowedHost at /
Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.17.194.253:31436'. You may need to add '172.17.194.253' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

But how can I bind the dynamically created HostIp of the pod to Django's `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Kubernetes 1.7 it is possible to request the HostIp of the pod in your kubernetes deployment file.[(1)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24657)

First adjust the deployment file to set the required environment variable for the HostIp. In the beneath scenario I set the POD_IP and the HOST_IP, as they are different. You can inject a variety of Kubernetes application data variables using environment variables in your Kubernetes deployment files, for more info about this topic look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/).

**frontend.service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-v1
  labels:
    app: frontend-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend-v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend-v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend-v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          image: yourremotename.azurecr.io/frontend-remote:v1
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8010
          env:
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: HOST_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.hostIP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: acr-secret
```

Now in you Django settings adjust the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` configuration to point to the `HOST_IP` environment variable.

**settings.py**

```
import os
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [os.environ.get('HOST_IP'), '127.0.0.1']
....
```

*Note that this allows the pod's HostIP as well als localhost for local development purposes.*

**Warning!** Some blog posts or tutorials advise you to set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` to accept all host IP's, but this is a serious security loophole. Don't do this!

Now redeploy your pod and your Django application should run smoothly again.

Comment: How does it work in your case? the hostIp is the internal node's ip, and the service (loadbalancer) external ip is different, I cannot access it from the pod's status

Comment: @Sheed That's a different question, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407345/kubernetes-pass-public-ip-of-load-balance-as-environment-variable-into-pod

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I already explored that solution, the thing is I don't currently have the possibility to buy a domain name which links to my cluster Ip, I'm searching for a more dynamic solution, otherwise I would go for the ingress + clusterIp or even manually editting the deployment after the external ip assignment

Comment: On which cloud provider platform are you working? I.e. AKS, EKS, or?

Comment: I'm working with Scaleway, I will probably be working with Azure later on

Comment: I've found a way in the provider's documentation :)

Comment: Using GKE, I had to use POD_IP instead of HOST_IP.

Comment: Why/how is using `'*'` in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` a serious security loophole for an app that is running inside pods in a k8s cluster?

Answer (score 3):

Or, simply add `Host: yourdomain.com` in the readinessProbe header. You can also customise the default path.

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: 8010  # Must be same as containerPort
    httpHeaders:
    - name: Host
      value: yourdomain.com
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. It's simpler than chaging code.